# I18Next does not find translation for languages be-fr and be-nl

Tags: i18next

I am using I18next to manage my translations. In the past we had subsites for languages with only two characters like en, nl, de etc. Now we are adding a new site with name be-nl and be-fr, for Belgium French and Belgium Dutch.

The problem I am facing right now is that i18next is not able to find the translation with the `-`. These are the resources I am passing to the options of `i18next.init`:

```
      resources: {  
        'be-fr': be_fr, 
        'be-nl': be_nl, 
        asia, cn, en, id, ng, nl 
      }
```

Where `be_fr` and `be_nl` are constants that hold the translation object for the whole subsite. The other languages are working fine, with the `be-fr` and `be-nl` site I get this error:

> i18next::translator: missingKey be-nl translation general.disclaimer

Is there any additional option I can add to i18next to solve this problem?

## EDIT

This my full i18next configuration:

```
      lng: lang,
      debug: false,
      initImmediate: true,
      fallbackLng: lang == 'be-nl' ? 'nl' : lang == 'be-fr' ? 'fr' : 'en',
      resources: {  
        'be-fr': be_fr, 
        'be-nl': be_nl, 
        asia, cn, en, id, ng, nl, fr
      }
```

Where `lang` is a variable in the main application containing the currently language of the site based on the path.

Comment: You may want to provide more information… the complete i18next config for example

Comment: @adrai Good point, I have added my full config, but the solution I found in my own answer solves the problem for me. So that is fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone stumbling upon this question I have used the `fallbackLng` options on `i18next.init`.

Using it like this:

```
fallbackLng: language == 'be-nl' ? 'nl' : language == 'be-fr' ? 'fr' : 'en',
```

This will atleast always show a translations, with a fallback to english.